# What denotes 'Vulnerabilities' section from 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.4' page?

Tags: maven, project, apache-commons-fileupload, maven-repository

Here I need to search latest version of dependency which is not vulnerable but as I navigate to maven repository page https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.4 , I see there is also vulnerabilities written under 'Vulnerabilities' section. I am in dilemma, whether this indicates a resolved vulnerability for given version or persisted still. Please clear whether this version is vulnerable or not?

```html
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Snapshot-->

[image: See Vulnerabilities section under depicted snapshot for commons-fileupload]

Answer (score 2):

Issue was reported in `commons-fileupload` [FILEUPLOAD-347](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FILEUPLOAD-347)

There are two vulnerabilities from dependencies:

- one on junit - it is not propagated to end user
- second - it's depends if  `commons-fileupload` use method `FileNameUtils.normalize` from `commons-io` - to check in [source code](https://github.com/apache/commons-fileupload/)

The best way is follow and / or ask such question in project tracking issue.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem with this dependency in my pom.xml. The last version of `poi-ooxml` uses `commons-io` 2.11.0 but `commons-fileupload` uses version 2.2 so I have "omitted for conflict with 2.2" for `poi-ooxml` in STS. Do you have a solution please because the JIRA ticket is still opened?